# Deserializing Firebase User Data response using Newtonsoft.Json library

Tags: c#, json.net, firebase-security

I am using C# to deserialize a Firebase Auth REST API Get User response using Newtonsoft.Json library. Below is a sample of the JSON output:

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse",
  "users": [
    {
      "localId": "asdfsdsfs",
      "email": "x.y@g.com",
      "passwordHash": "asdsdfsdfd",
      "emailVerified": false,
      "passwordUpdatedAt": 1985545511525,
      "providerUserInfo": [
        {
          "providerId": "password",
          "federatedId": "x.y@g.com",
          "email": "x.y@g.com",
          "rawId": "x.y@g.com"
        }
      ],
      "validSince": "16496321050",
      "lastLoginAt": "16874526844",
      "createdAt": "164123654725",
      "lastRefreshAt": "2022-03-19T16:53:56.844Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I used this code to attempt to deserialize it:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>> responseText = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>>(request.downloadHandler.text);
```

However, I get this error:

> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]].
> Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable
> (System.Object value, System.Type initialType, System.Type targetType)
> (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast (System.Object
> initialValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Type
> targetType) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType
> (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Object value,
> System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Type
> targetType) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0) Rethrow as
> JsonSerializationException: Error converting value
> "identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse" to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]'.
> Path 'kind', line 2, position 50.
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType
> (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Object value,
> System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Type
> targetType) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal
> (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember,
> System.Object existingValue) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateDictionary
> (System.Collections.IDictionary dictionary, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader
> reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonDictionaryContract contract,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty,
> System.String id) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject
> (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember,
> System.Object existingValue) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal
> (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract,
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember,
> System.Object existingValue) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize
> (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
> System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) (at
> <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal
> (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) (at
> <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader
> reader, System.Type objectType) (at
> <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value,
> System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) (at
> <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value,
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) (at
> <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value)
> (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that it can't convert a string into a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` - the json values don't represent `List<Dictionary<,>>`.

You could deserialize the json to `Dictionary<string, object>` or `dynamic`:

```cs
Dictionary<string, object> responseText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
// or
dynamic responseText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

---

However, unless the json is dynamic and changing constantly, a better option is to deserialize to a concrete class or classes which model the json.  There are apps online to help you convert the json to C# classes. You could use [json2csharp.com](https://json2csharp.com/), [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/), or VisualStudio Paste JSON as Classes.

I used json2csharp, which output the following (including how to deserialize the json):

```cs
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

public class ProviderUserInfo
{
    public string providerId { get; set; }
    public string federatedId { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string rawId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string localId { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string passwordHash { get; set; }
    public bool emailVerified { get; set; }
    public long passwordUpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public List<ProviderUserInfo> providerUserInfo { get; set; }
    public string validSince { get; set; }
    public string lastLoginAt { get; set; }
    public string createdAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastRefreshAt { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
}
```

[Online example of all 3 methods](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9SVa45)

Comment: Thanks it works, I used the class. Assuming I cast it to a Dictionary, how do I convert the object to a List?

Comment: @kbb not sure what you mean? Why do you need a dictionary/list? The json you've shown doesn't represent a list, but the `users` property is a list - `foreach (var user in deserialized.users){...}`

Answer (score 1):

use this [site](https://app.quicktype.io/) for convert your json to c# class

and this is your model

```
public class ModelDeserialize
    {
        [JsonProperty("kind")]
        public string Kind { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("users")]
        public User[] Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty("localId")]
        public string LocalId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("passwordHash")]
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("emailVerified")]
        public bool EmailVerified { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("passwordUpdatedAt")]
        public long PasswordUpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("providerUserInfo")]
        public ProviderUserInfo[] ProviderUserInfo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("validSince")]
        public string ValidSince { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastLoginAt")]
        public string LastLoginAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("createdAt")]
        public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastRefreshAt")]
        public DateTimeOffset LastRefreshAt { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProviderUserInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("providerId")]
        public string ProviderId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("federatedId")]
        public string FederatedId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rawId")]
        public string RawId { get; set; }
    }
```

finally deserialize

```
 var dese = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelDeserialize>(json);
 (var datas in dese.Users){
 Console.WriteLine(datas.Email);
```

check the [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w76sic)